# How to create a package that contains script to remove mrt.exe remotely from multiple Windows machines

Tags: windows, powershell, executable, delete-file

I have created this PowerShell script:

`Remove-Item "C:\Windows\System32\mrt.exe" -Force`

it did not work, below are the action logs. it says 'path not found' but it does exist on the server.

```
- 006|2023-02-07T14:09:14Z|CommandLine: cmd /c "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File .\MRT_removal.ps1
- 007|Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\mrt.exe' because it does
- 008|not exist.
- 009|At C:\Program Files (x86)\Tanium\Tanium
- 010|Client\Downloads\Action_1134485\MRT_removal.ps1:1 char:1
- 011|+ Remove-Item "C:\Windows\System32\mrt.exe" -Force
- 012|+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
- 013| + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\System32\mrt.exe:Str
- 014| ing) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
- 015| + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Remov
- 016| eItemCommand
```

Comment: Where are you running the script from and how? System32 is a protected path and you may need to run with elevated permissions

Comment: cmd /c "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File .\MRT_removal.ps1 this is how i used it.

Comment: I am not familiar with PS, but can you explain how this is being run remotely? Are you running the script locally on the remote machine, or are you wanting to run a command to remotely communicate with the remote machine to delete the file? (I can't see any remote machine specification in your command).

Comment: i am using Tanium to deploy the package.